# magento bundle products grid not showing

Tags: magento, bundle

I have a problem that I can't fix. I don't know why, but when I want to create a bundle product and I want to add products, grid is not showing. I click on "Add new Option", then on "add selection", then the place where there should be the grid appears but without the grid.

you can see a capture here: http://test.isabeldepedro.com/foto.png

it should be like this: http://test.isabeldepedro.com/foto2.png

I've been checking files:

adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml
adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option/search.phtml

but they look fine, are the original ones.

The grid is been showed on all the rest of the admin options.

Thanks for your time,

Màrius

Answer (score 0):

Just click "Reset Filter" or "Search" and Enjoy!

By default that grid does not show any products.

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thanks for your reply, the problem is that I don't have the option to reset filter or search. As you can see on this image  http://test.isabeldepedro.com/foto.png I don't see the grid.

Comment: Do you have any errors in browser console or in "your-project/var/log/" folder in files system.log or exception.log?

Comment: I've activated the logs, but it doesn't produce error logs. Does the back end generate errors on the system.log or exception.log? or just the front end?

Comment: The error may be recorded, but maybe not. Try check ajax request - http://your-site.com/index.php/admin/bundle_selection/search/?isAjax=true - check response.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I'm back to work. I've checked the jacascript console, and when I click on "Add selection", there is an error, you can see it on the post below... I can't past it here

Comment: Regarding the ajax request, I received that message {"error":true,"message":"Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page."}

Comment: I've found the problem!! There was incompatibility with a pluggin. I uninstalled it and it works again.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the JavaScript console, and when I click on "Add selection", there is an error:

> POST http://test.isabeldepedro.com/index.php/admin/bundle_selection/search/key/80415147e69e6378f4fb1bbf3b4677f8/?isAjax=true 500 (Internal Server Error) prototype.js:1530Ajax.Request.Class.create.request 
>   
>   prototype.js:1530Ajax.Request.addMethods.initialize loader.js:61(anonymous function) prototype.js:429(anonymous function) prototype.js:141(anonymous function) prototype.js:391Ajax.Updater.Class.create.initialize prototype.js:1754(anonymous function) prototype.js:429klass prototype.js:101Bundle.Selection.showSearch VM189:71onclick (index):1